# How to connect MongoClient to secondary replica set?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am trying to use the MongoClient GUI app to connect to a MongoDB replica set.  This is the structure of my URL but it is not working:

```
mongodb://username:password@host-01:27017,host-02:27017,host-03:27017/mydb?authSource=mydb&replicaSet=rs0&ssl=true&sslValidate=false
```

I get an error similar to this:

```
Couldn't connect: server host-03:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}
```

Comment: You did not provide the `replicaSet` option

Comment: @AliDehghani thanks, I have updated the question and error message.

Comment: Have you confirmed that host-03 is up and running correctly? For example by checking the output from [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/).

Comment: @VinceBowdren yes, it works with command line mongo client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was on a Mac. host-01, host-02 and host-03 were pointing to the wrong ip addresses in /etc/hosts

The servers were responding to ping requests, but the wrong servers were responding.  So make sure your servers are pointing to actual MongoDB nodes.

Comment: Hi Roberto; if you have solved your problem, you should Accept this answer so the question no longer shows up as unanswered.